# Choose vga output on port replicator

Tags: graphics, vga

I have an Acer laptop with a port replicator, the Easyport IV.

#### System specs:

- Acer laptop, Travelmate 8172
- Intel HD graphics
- Ubuntu 12.10

#### My problem:

I have two VGA ports. One directly on my laptop and one on my easyport of course.

Most of the times I am forced to use the VGA socket on my laptop, which somehow defeats the purpose of a having port replicator.

`xrandr -q` doesn't list it as a different device of course. Also I don't get a `udev` signal. Sometimes, on rare occasions it will mystically pick the VGA on my Easyport, but I can't trigger that.

How can I choose the VGA output on my port replicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My System:

- Travelmate 8572
- Easyport
- Arch Linux (Kernel 3.14)

I noticed that VGA and Ethernet at the easyport are only working, if the sound is muted. The following command solves the issue temporarily for me and i have not noticed any side effects yet.

```
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x1b SET_EAPD 0x00
```

Please tell us if it solves your problem too

Edit: hda-verb is contained in package "alsa-tools"

Comment: This just did the trick. Hooray!!! No more messing around with the cable.